# FactoryBot ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Year is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

When I run my rspec test I receive validation error `year is required`, but in my factory I set year value. I don't know why I receive this error.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :syllabus do
    year  { 2019 } 
    cycle_academic { "1" }
    modality { "presencial" }
    syllabus_content { "{}" }
    association :doc_template 
    association :user 
    association :curriculum_course
    association :cycle 
    credits { 4 }
    weekly_hours { 5 }

    trait :syllabus_estrategia do
      course { :estrategia }
    end

    trait :syllabus_ingles1 do
      course { :ingles1 }
    end

    trait :syllabus_ingles2 do
      course { :ingles2 }
    end

    trait :syllabus_matematica do
      course { :matematica }
    end    
  end
end
```

In my rspec file I invoque this factory with this line

```
it "order to approver" do 
  syllabus_general =  FactoryBot.create(:syllabus) 
end
```

Comment: What type has `year` column in db?

Comment: Could one of the associated models also require a year (and its factory not be providing one)?

Comment: @smathy you were right . In my model associated i dont set a value of year . Its works now. Thank you. Please 
Can you place your answer to be able to accept it and earn your points?.

Comment: Hey cool, I've tried to formulate my answer in a way that might help other people who happen to stumble over your question.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the `year` value in the factory you've displayed, so my guess would be that one of the associated models you have in this factory also requires a `year` and the default factory for that other model doesn't provide it.

With factories always be thinking what other things are happening.